# At what location does pafy save the downloaded file?

Tags: python-3.x, pafy

So I used the pafy library to download an audio file directly from youtube, but I don't know at what location the file is saved.

```
import pafy
video = pafy.new("dQw4w9WgXcQ")
bestaudio = video.getbestaudio()
bestaudio.download()
```

This is the code I used. The song was downloaded but I don't know where.

Comment: Assuming the script is correct, can you please confirm if its downloaded in the current working directory (where your script is )

Comment: There's no .mp3 file in the folder where the pafy library is saved, but I'm sure it's downloaded because when I run the script again it says file with the same name exists on the location.

Comment: Check the folder where your script is saved and where are you running it from!

Answer (score 2):

the file saved in the current working directory, you can know it using this code

```
import os 
print(os.cwd())
```

and to change the current working directory use:

```
os.chdir(r"type your own path")
```